# Why the List<string> Lightnings is all the time contain 0 items empty?

Tags: c#

In Form1 I have this in the top of the Form:

```
Lightnings_Extractor.PDF pdf1;
```

Then in the constructor of `Form1` I have:

```
pdf1 = new Lightnings_Extractor.PDF();
```

Then in the bottom of `Form1` I have:

```
private void deleteSelectedLightningsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to delete " + Lightnings_Extractor.ListBoxControl.counter +  " files ? Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
    {

    }
    else
    {
           for (int i = 0; i < pdf1.Lightnings.Count; i++)
            {

            }
    }
}
```

And I see that `Lightnings` have items inside. 
But then when I click on the: `deleteSelectedLightningsToolStripMenuItem_Click` in `Form1` I see that `Lightnings` is empty count 0. I can't figure out why.

Comment: ok... so how much of this code can be deleted such that you still have the issue (and we would be able to recreate it)?   It's a lot to take in.

Comment: Way to much code, man. The idea is to include only enough to demonstrate your problem, not your entire program.

Comment: I agree.  Unfortunately you're going to get mostly TL;DR reactions from this huge pile of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LightningExtractor` objects in `Form1` and `Lightnings_Mode` are *different* objects.

You need to be passing the same object around.

Comment: Oded i tried in Form1 to make the pdf1 variable public: public Lightnings_Extractor.PDF pdf1; then in Lightnings_Mode to use it like this: public Lightnings_Mode(Form1 f1)
        {
            InitializeComponent(); and then to use it: f1.pdf1.Lightnings.Add(item.ToString()); but im getting an error on Form1 on the pdf1 variable: Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Lightnings_Extractor.PDF' is less accessible than property 'Extracting_Frames.Form1.mypdf'

Comment: @user1196715 - You will need to make the class `PDF` `public` as well.